# como hago un select con audios?

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero hacer un select y que al cliquear en cada opción reproduzca un audio.

```
<select>
        <option id="1"><audio src="audio1.mp3">audio1</audio></option>
        <option id="2"><audio src="audio2.mp3">audio2</audio></option>
        <option id="3"><audio src="audio3.mp3">audio3</audio></option>
    </select>
```

necesito hacer algo en JS o se puede hacer con HTML?

Comment: Con un maquetado html aparte.
O sea, los selects son para alfanuméricos.
Generalmente lo que veo en otros proyectos es generar un html que simule ser un select con el contenido que necesita (imágenes principalmente) y la lógica de selección lo hacen con un JS que se encarga de establecer los "selected"

Comment: Tu pregunta debe ser más específico. Que quieres con el Select ? Listar audios y reproducir ahi mismo ? O tener una lista Select de nombres de audios y al seleccionar reproducir ese audio en una etiqueta única de audio ? Que quieres hacer en realidad ? `select` es para listar números y textos, pero en este caso debe ser algo diferente para abrir una ventana de lista

Comment: muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
// url de ejemplo 
var url = "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-";
// agregamos un evento listener de tipo change al select
document.querySelector("select")
.addEventListener("change",function(e){
    // seleccionamos e.target = el elemento que genero el evento
    // del selected otenemos los options
    // de los options accedemos al indice seleccionado
    // y por ultimo recuperamos su texto osea el nombre
    let opt = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text;
    // seleccionamos el audio 
    let audio = document.querySelector("audio");
    // pausamos el anterior
    audio.pause();
    // concatenamos el url mas el nombre mas .mp3
    audio.src  = url + opt +".mp3";
    // le damos play 
    audio.play();
})
```

```html
<select>
<option id="1">Song-1</option>
<option id="2">Song-2</option>
<option id="3">Song-3</option>
<option id="4">Song-4</option>
<option id="5">Song-5</option>
</select>

<audio src="audio1.mp3" controls>audio1</audio>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

En el ejemplo de

```html
<button>play</button>

<audio class="sound1" src="https://hpr.dogphilosophy.net/test/wav.wav" ></audio>
<audio class="sound2" src="https://hpr.dogphilosophy.net/test/mp3.mp3" ></audio>
```

Necesitas usar `.play()` para iniciar el audio, y usar `$(selector).get(0)` para el objeto audio.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  if ( true ) {
    $('.sound1').get(0).play();
  } else {
    $('.sound2').get(0).play();
  }
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aL6bemfo/)

Comment: muchas gracias!